# One does not belong. (But they are all wrong, aren't they?)

Tags: odd-one-out

One of these six equations below does not belong to the group. Which one? and why?

[image]

Text

10+14=23

10+15=24

10+16=25

10+17=26

10+18=27

10+19=28

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the secret to this puzzle lies away from mathematics. After all, each of the equations makes no mathematical sense in base-10 (i.e. 'they are all wrong', as the title attests). Instead, we should:

> count up the number of **letters** in each of the numbers written out in English. Once we do that, five of the 'equations' are *balanced*, with the same number of letters on either side of the equals sign, and just one is not:
>
>  [11] TEN + FOURTEEN = TWENTY THREE [11]
>  [10] TEN + FIFTEEN = TWENTY FOUR [10]
>  [10] TEN + SIXTEEN = TWENTY FIVE [10]
>  **[12] TEN + SEVENTEEN = TWENTY SIX [9]**
>  [11] TEN + EIGHTEEN = TWENTY SEVEN [11]
>  [11] TEN + NINETEEN = TWENTY EIGHT [11]
>
>  This way, the **fourth 'equation'** is the odd-one-out.

Comment: *"I think the secret to this puzzle lies away from mathematics."* Not much of a "secret", really, considering three and a half out of four answers don't even mention maths...

Answer (score 10):

The odd one out is

> 10 + 19 = 28

Because

> All of the equations are correct if you interpret the second addend in base 9, but you can't have a 9 digit in base 9.

Comment: That is like saying "the last one is the odd one out because it's the only one at the end of the list"... kind of just making a rule up to fit a random answer.

Comment: No, the poster would be correct even if the list were re-ordered.  it isn't his fault the OP included no other 9s.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe

> 10+15=24.

Because it's the only one that's actually right, in a sense.

> (2 strokes to write 10 and 4 strokes to write 15 = 2&4, or 24).

Comment: Do you write 5 in 3 strokes? Isn't it 1 stroke like every other letter, or 2 if you don't like going backwards with your first stroke?

Comment: I just counted distinct lines and curves, but it is certainly a long shot. I imagine this question has lots of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> the second one? 15 being the only teen that does (phonetically) change its non-teen bit, "fifteen",  not "fiveteen" ("thirteen is not in the list and "eighteen" sounds the same as "eightteen" would).

Comment: Not really @loopy walt.  Gur gvgyr vf n pyhr